# ImgAreaSelect Вывести координаты изображения

Tags: jquery, изображения, php, javascript

Идея такова- нужно из [этого плагина](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect) вывести координаты -x1,x2,y1,y2 - что бы я их мог методом пост завбрать и вставить сюда

```
$inFile = $urlImage;
```

$outFile = "test-cropped.jpg";
$image = new Imagick($inFile);
$image->cropImage(x1,x2,y1,y2 );
$image->writeImage($outFile);

вот только ни как не могу понять как их поймать - $_POST['x1']  так ничего не выводит

Comment: [смотрим вот сюда](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html#api-methods)


*getSelection*

Comment: @нгш, давай так, ты мне пришлешь 20 уе. А я тебе передам скрипт, который охрененно ресайзит картинки. Скрипт я писал самолично))) . Херня все это, то, что ты только что прислал.((

Comment: @eicto
не совсем понимаю как getSelection вставить в мой код пхп

Comment: @eicto не дает глупые ответы на глупые вопросы. ТС должен определиться

Comment: определится с чем?

Comment: код php тут мало причем, с помошью getSelection вы получаете параметры (x1,x2,y1,y2) вставляете их в форму и отправляете вместе с изображением в код php

Comment: у меня изображение идёт через пхп, в общем я всё сделал, спс за подсказки, получилось так
$orient = $_POST['orient'];
$offset = $_POST['offset'];
$x = $_POST['fbrush-width']*1.58;   
$y = $_POST['fbrush-height']*1.6;      
   
 if ($orient == 1) {  $x2 = $offset ; $y2 = 0; $y = 9000; } 
 elseif ($orient == 2) {$y2 = $offset ; $x2 = 0; $x = 1000; }


$inFile = $urlImage;
$outFile = "test-cropped.jpg";
$image = new Imagick($inFile);
$image->cropImage($x,$y,$x2,$y2);
$image->writeImage($outFile);

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться callback'ом плагина [onSelectChange](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/examples-callback.html)

```
(function ($) {
    function sendCoordinate(img, selection) {
        $.post('/your/script', {
            x1: selection.x1,
            y1: selection.y1,
            x2: selection.x2,
            y2: selection.y2
        });
    }

    $('#image').imgAreaSelect({aspectRatio: '1:1', onSelectChange: sendCoordinate});
})(jQuery)
```

И на стороне сервера просто принимаем $_POST-массив с ключами x1, x2, y1, y2

Если же отправка координат планируется через форму, форма представлена в виде

```
<form action="/your/script" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="x1" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="y1" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="x2" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="y2" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

и заполняется при выборе области на картинке, тогда после отправки формы также на стороне сервера получаем массив $_POST с ключами x1, x2, y1, y2